# How to get metadata/headers of an Amazon S3 Bucket in Python (Boto lib) like in Openstack Swift?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, openstack-swift

I'd like to get the list of metadata/headers of an amazon s3 bucket?

I can get the metadata in OpenStack Swift Storage like following ->
the curl command that request the metadata:

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/v1/AUTH_test/container1 -X HEAD -H "X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tk6194fghrt"
```

response for above curl command:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Length: 0
X-Container-Object-Count: 6
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Trans-Id: tx0ff9f8541e2c4e019dea1-0053eb48a7
Date: Wed, 13 Aug 2014 11:14:47 GMT
X-Container-Meta-Century: Nineteenthsssssssssssss
X-Timestamp: 1399987571.97634
X-Container-Meta-Author: Mustafa
X-Container-Bytes-Used: 3978833
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
X-Trans-Id: tx1c2734f1e4ca4f3e835da-0053eb497d
```

In openstack swift I can get the above metadata of a swift container(bucket) by using the python-swiftclient API.
I want to do same thing for AmazonS3 bucket. so, how can I get the **metadata** of an **AmazonS3 bucket** with **Python** ?(I am using **boto** library)
Is it possible or am I "beating the air"?

**UPDATE:**
I'm trying to get metadata of a **bucket** not the keys of bucket.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this boto snippet code:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
conn = S3Connection('<aws access key>', '<aws secret key>')
mybucket = conn.get_bucket('mybucket')
for key in mybucket:
    key = mybucket.get_key(key.name)
    print key.name
    print key.get_metadata('revision')
```

You can read more information for boto on : https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html

Hope that helps.

UPDATE:

Something else that you can try:

```
resp = conn.make_request("HEAD", mybucket)
print resp.getheaders()
```

Hope you are seeing some metadata that you wanted in the response headers.

Comment: I'm using these codes for getting metadata from key of buckets.  But I'm looking for bucket not the keys

Comment: I see. I'm not too sure about the bucket itself. I have updated the answer with something else that you may be able to try.